# Apple template iOS file with core-data and table views

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I understand what basic synthesizing does in objective C but I don't understand what Apple is doing here.  This shows up in the RootViewController of a project template with core-data and table views.

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext=__managedObjectContext;
```

What is the purpose of "__" and what are you doing when your are sysnthesising a object and setting equal to another object that is not used anywhere else in the view controller, although it is used in the app delegate?

I also notice that __managedObjectContext is released in the dealloc method but not managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *reason* to do this is to protect the programmer from himself.  Defensive programming.  There are times when you want to access the value via the accessor (`self.managedObjectContext`)  and other times you want to efficiently access the instance variable directly (`__managedObjectContext`).

This is a more general issue, and not specific to CoreData or managed object contexts.  Without the `= __managedObjectContext` portion, the instance variable and it accessor would have the same name.  It's not an uncommon occurrence for someone to write `managedObjectContext = foo;` which will forgo the accessor and the needed `retain`.  With the change of variable name you, your future self, and other readers of the code will more likely notice something problematic like `__managedObjectContext = foo;`

I will often shorten names inside the class as well with something like `@synthesize managedObjectContext=_moc;` as a personal preference - keeping some of my code from wrapping due to long names.  But the verbose and more readable interface is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

It's not another object.  That specifies the name of the instance variable that backs the property.  For more information, see [Declared Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1).

Comment: OK it gives the object a name which is also described in the referenced article.  I understand doing that when you want to give it different names to make the code more readable internally and externally to the viewController but I don't understand what value Apples name provides.  What's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this piece of code:

```
@interface A {
    Foo *_foo;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) Foo *foo;

@end


@implementation A 

@synthesize foo = _foo;

// ...

- (void)dealloc {
    [_foo release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

In this case the leading underscore ("_") is by *convention*, a way to differentiate between the name of the instance variable (iVar) and the name of the property. What this means is, you have a coding convention for differentiating between property access (via accessors) and direct access (via a pointer).

Also note, there is no value assignment whatsoever done in `@synthesize foo = _foo;`. This simply indicates that the synthesized accessors should use the iVar named `_foo` for storage.

Lastly, since `_foo` is the name of your iVar, you have to write `[_foo release]`. It is the iVar that's being released, not the property (see the distinction?).

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Properties in Objective-C 2.0 are not objects but rather methods.

Back in Objective-C 1.0, you had to create your own accessors like so:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController  {
  NSManagedObjectContext *__managedObjectContext;
}
@end

@implementation RootViewController

-(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{
  if (__managedObjectContext!=nil) {
    return __managedObjectContext;
  }

  //... else initialize the context
  [__managedObjectContext retain];
  return __managedObjectContext;
}

-(void) setManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{
  if (__managedObjectContext!=nil) {
    [__managedObjectContext release];
    __managedObjectContext=nil;
  }
  __managedObjectContext=managedObjectContext;
  [__managedObjectContext retain];
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc=[self managedObjectContext];
```

or

```
[self setManagedObjectContext:anotherContext];
```

As long as you always called the accessors you could be confident that the instance variable object would always be properly retained in released.

In Objective-C 2.0 the combined @property and @synthesize directives automate this entire property.

The property declaration is telling the pre-compiler what methods to create by name, readwrite, atomicity, retention etc.The synthesize directive tell the pre-compiler what property methods to autogenerate if they don't exist. By default it will also create an instance variable of the same name as a property. If you add the `= someOtherSymbol`, it creates an instance variable of different name so that you won't accidentally refer to it.

The self-dot notation automatically calls the accessor method instead of directly accessing the instance variable. This is important because if you do this:

```
__managedObjectContext= aContext;
```

... the newly passed `aContext` object is neither retained nor released and might either disappear unexpectedly or leak memory. That is because the direct reference does not call an accessor method whereas:

```
self.manageObjectContext= aContext;
```

or
    [self setManagedObjectContext:aContext];

both call accessor methods and automatically handle retention.